# Eidolon Grabbing and Constricting

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple, summoner, eidolon

So designing a new Eidolon with tbe serpentine base form. Using such he qualifies for the Constrict evolution

> An eidolon gains powerful muscles that allow it to crush those it grapples. Whenever the eidolon successfully grapples a foe using the grab evolution, it deals additional damage equal to the amount of damage dealt by the attack used by the grab evolution. This evolution is only available to eidolons of the serpentine form

My original question is this do you double the damage done by the original attack or do you reroll the original attack damage?

The reason i need this clarification is because of the Final Embrace feat tree, with Final Embrace Master stating

> Benefit: Double the number of damage dice for your constrict special attack.

As a follow up bonus question. My Eidolon has 4 Natural Primary Claw attacks. Can he hit with a claw, grab the opponent dealing constrict damage. Drop the poor thing, than rinse and repeat the other 3 attacks? Or do i need to make the grab the last attack?

Comment: Based on this question and comments, I must ask: *What level is this summoner?* I mean, an eidolon with four extra attacks from the claws, rake, and 1 or 2 *more* attacks from the base form means a summoner of at least level 14 (when the maximum number of eidolon attacks is 6) or 19 (when it's 7)! I mean, that's cool, but I *am* curious. Also, be aware that the prerequisites for [Final Embrace](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#final-embrace) *et al.* were changed by errata making them so an eidolon might not qualify without GM permission.

Comment: I wasnt aware of the new errata stating it as a racial ability (thanks for the heads up). Also it is a level 11. Currently he has a max of 5 attacks a turn. So I'm not to make use of all my natural attacks as the build has 1 bite, 1 tail slap, and 4 claws. The claws are the best damage because along with a free grab/constrict if two hit they deal additional rending damage.

Comment: You're welcome. Just so I understand, the GM said it was okay if the eidolon exceeded the printed maximum number of attacks because the eidolon chooses not to use all the natural attacks at its disposal? You've bought the GM pizza, right? `;-)`

Comment: He is a rather flexible DM and is allowing it mainly because The shafting you get because of the feat tax of Ability Focus (Constrict).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, the wording is clear: there is no reroll, and the additional damage dealt is the same as the original roll.

With the Final Embrace Master feat, you just double the number of original dices on your grab attack, but only if you decide to use constrict on that grab (so if you use a normal grab you only get to roll the original attack)

For the second one, tecnically they're all free actions:

> Grab (Ex): An eidolon becomes adept at grappling foes, gaining the
>   grab ability. [...] Whenever the eidolon makes a successful attack of
>   the selected type, it can attempt **a free combat maneuver check**. If
>   successful, the eidolon grapples the target. [...]

And

> Grapple: As a standard action, you can attempt to grapple a foe, [...]
>   Although both creatures have the grappled condition, you can, as the
>   creature that initiated the grapple, **release the grapple as a free
>   action**

so you can make a full-round attack, get your free grapple/break grapple checks and deal damage with every check. However, as for the free action type description, the DM has the last word on how many free actions you get during your round, so results may vary.

If you have difficulty imagining a creature with claws grappling an opponent multiple times, imagine a creature with tentacles instead, establishing a hold on different body parts and trying to crush each one.

Comment: So if i choose to use the Constrict at that point i would need to roll the extra dice and add them in to the damage the claw had made. Am i understanding that correctly?

Comment: As I understand it, you would attack with the claw, roll the damage two times, then double it (as for constrict)

Comment: No, the damage would be (for Medium) 3d6. You double the Constrict damage, but not the original Claw damage. Constrict deals damage that is equal "the attack used *by the grab evolution*", not the damage you did with the swing. Also, consider transmogrifying your Claws into Pincers. +2 to Grapples and keep the d6 damage dice.

Comment: The claws base damage currently are 1D8+12 (large Size with improved natural attack claw). So your saying each claw attack would do that, however on a successful grab it would do an addition 2D8+12? Also pincers are nice however I lose an attack for each one and cannot use the rend evolution.